# Hibernate envers throws ClassCastException: HashMap cannot cast to Integer

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have configured to use Hibernate envers with my SpringBoot 2.x application. Here is the configuration in my properties file.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy=org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix=private_
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=ims_audit
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=
```

My entity class looks like this:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Respondent extends Auditable<Respondent> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="respondent_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer respondentId;

    @Column(name="address_line1")
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name="address_line2")
    private String addressLine2;

    private String cage;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    private String county;

    private String duns;

    @Column(name="eeo1_hdq_nbr")
    private String eeo1HdqNbr;

    @Column(name="eeo1_unit_nbr")
    private String eeo1UnitNbr;

    private String ein;

    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="eml_compatability_grade")
    private BigDecimal emlCompatabilityGrade;

    @Column(name="eml_employer_id")
    private Integer emlEmployerId;

    @Column(name="eml_state")
    private String emlState;

    @Column(name="eml_verification_on")
    private LocalDateTime emlVerificationOn;

    private String extension;

    private String fax;

    @Column(name="institution_type")
    private String institutionType;

    private String mediation;

    @Column(name="naics_code")
    private String naicsCode;

    private String name;

    @Column(name="number_of_employees")
    private String numberOfEmployees;

    @Column(name="original_id")
    private Integer originalId;

    private String phone;

    @Column(name="position_statement_due")
    private LocalDateTime positionStatementDue;

    @Column(name="respondent_password")
    private String respondentPassword;

    private String state;

    @Column(name="zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @NotAudited
    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "respondent")
    private ChargeInquiry chargeInquiry;

    @NotAudited
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "respondent")
    private Set<AdditionalAddress> additionalAddressSet;
```

While inserting a record, I got this error:

```
Hibernate: insert into ims_audit.private_Respondent (REVTYPE, REVEND, address_line1, address_line2, cage, city, country, county, duns, eeo1_hdq_nbr, eeo1_unit_nbr, ein, email_address, eml_compatability_grade, eml_employer_id, eml_state, eml_verification_on, extension, fax, institution_type, mediation, naics_code, name, number_of_employees, original_id, phone, position_statement_due, respondent_password, state, zip_code, respondent_id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [12] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [13] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [14] as [NUMERIC] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [15] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [16] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [17] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [18] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [19] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [20] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [21] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [22] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [23] as [VARCHAR] - [abc corp]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [24] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-20 13:47:24 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [25] as [INTEGER] - *****[{REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 56, revisionDate = Feb 20, 2020 1:47:24 PM), respondentId=50}]*
2020-02-20 13:47:24 ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer****
```

I do not understand why it tries to insert a hashmap of "DefaultRevisionEntity" into a REV column which is an Integer.

Comment: Try renaming the "originalId" property, because it is internally used by Hibernate Envers I think (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/search?q=originalId&unscoped_q=originalId). Maybe this causes the problem.

Comment: Yes. it was indeed the problem. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my problem and providing the solution. Once again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, it was just a guess. Glad it worked! I have rewritten the comment as an answer. Please accept it, if this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the property name `originalId` is used by Hibernate internally, see:

- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/search?q=originalId&unscoped_q=originalId

Renaming the property `originalId` to something else fixes the problem.